# How to select default values for stored proc arguments?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Facing a problem getting the default values of the procedure parameters:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo(p_arg VARCHAR2:= 'FOO')
IS
BEGIN
 NULL;
END;
/

SELECT argument_name, default_value
  FROM sys.all_arguments
 WHERE object_name = 'FOO';

 ARGUMENT_NAME | DEFAULT_VALUE
 ------------------------------
 P_ARG         |  (Memo)
```

The default values I set for the procedure parameters are not displayed in the output. All I see is (Memo) in the default_value column.
The Oracle documentation does not help as this feature is "Reserved for future use": 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17615/refrn20015.htm#i1573843

Is there another way to read default values of the procedure parameters please?

Comment: I think this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065575/how-do-i-open-a-stored-procedure-and-edit-it-in-sqlplus

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/13803099/409172

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the `default_value` column of `*_arguments`  data dictionary views never gets populated. Oracle, for some reason, reserves it for *future use* for a quite sometime. You can see that an argument has or has not a default value assigned to it(column `defaulted`), but crucial information about actual default value is missing. To some extent it considered to be a documentation bug. Worth to note that the `dbms_describe` package does not provide information on actual default values of arguments either.   So it leaves you with one option to retrieve default values of arguments - stored procedure source code parsing, that can be obtained by querying `*_source` views.

Comment: See bug 183707, just for laughs.  It's sad that this has been a bug for 20 years.  But also kind of impressive that they've been able to keep track a bug for that long.